# Add Unix Executable to Mac OS X Dock

Tags: macos, dock

I can't drag Unix Executables to the dock like I can with other executables. Is there another way to put them there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Platypus http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus to build a MacOSX compatable program which calls a bash script/executable.

Comment: Looks like this program can't be run on M2 Macbook Pro

Answer (score 2):

Platypus will do the job fairly.

However, if you are not in the favour of installing any other software then you can also achieve the same using AppleScript:

**Step 1:** open Apple Script Editor from Spotlight search.

**Step 2:** write this command

```
to run
    do shell script "path_to_unix_executable"
end run
```

**Step 3:** Save it as an application bundle.

**Step 4:** Run

Answer (score 1):

Platypus is nice. An alternative is to create an Applescript application with a `do shell script` command.

Here's the relevant apple technote:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html

Comment: and the AppleScript can be saved as an `app` by File-> Export in the AppleScript editor. The drag & drop the `app` on your dock.